# What injectors are typically used for mixing sewage sludge?

Tags: civil-engineering, waste-water-treatment

One typical way to heat sewage sludge digesters is to pump the sludge through heat exchangers, raw sludge is injected before or after the HX. What kind of injectors are typically used for this?

I'm not loking to brainstorm ideas what *could* be used, I'm looking for solutions that are common and proven in the field.

Comment: Well, if you are a licenced WW operation, you call your pump company and they send out a rep. If this is a homework question or school design project, please say so and show us what you have found so far. It took me all of one minute to google this, but I knew pretty much exactly what to query. (When I was living in the Florida Keys, every hotel and resort had their own complete small WW system since there was no sewer system on the islands. The Keys were plenty warm, we didn't have to use heaters.)

Comment: It took me longer becauser google results for injectors (even with the keywords sewage sludge etc) are swamped with results pertinent for cars, but I *think* I found my answer after posting this question.